# How do I ensure that each and every argument was passed to a constructor in JS

Tags: javascript, class, object, error-handling, constructor

I have the following two classes, where `Circle` is an extension of `Entity`. The constructor for `Entity` uses a single argument which is supposed to be an Object, in order to allow customization of a new `Entity`. Due to the more specific nature of the `Circle`, I created a constructor with specific arguments, which I want to be less flexible. Here are the class declarations:

```
class Entity {
  constructor(e) {
    //use the attributes in the passed object to create a new Entity.
    this.x = e.x; //position
    this.y = e.y;
    this.vY = this.vX = 0; //velocity
    this.aX = this.aY = 0; //acceleration

  }
}
class Circle extends Entity {
  constructor(x, y, r, color) {
    super({"x":x,"y":y}); //create Entity with given position;
    this.r = r;
    this.color = color;
  }
}
```

I have also written a function `addEntity(entity)` which is defined as follows:

```
addEntity(e) {
    var ent_properties = Object.keys(e);
    if(e.type) { //create a specific predefined Entity type, if thats what you want!
      switch(e.type) {
        case "circle":
          try {
            this.entities.push(new Circle(e.x, e.y, e.r, e.color));
          } catch (err) { console.error(err); }
          break;
        default:
          console.error("Invalid Entity Type Created: ");
          console.error(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

Obviously, there is still a good amount of work to be done here, and a lot of context that I left out (which isn't exactly relevant to the question at hand, but my issue that I bring to everyone here is this:

If I were to call

```
e.addEntity({
      "type": "circle",
      "x": x,
      "y": y,
      "r": 100,
      "color": "black"
    });
```

This creates a valid object, with every relevant value filled. However, let's say that I forgot to include `"r"`, or instead of writing `"r"`, I wrote `"radius"`, what would be the best way to catch that? As of right now, it just creates a `Circle` with `this.r = undefined`.

Additionally, what is the best way to make sure that the object I give to `addEntity` has all the necessary attributes, depending on the type of `Entity` that I want to create? I want to be able to add MORE types, while also making sure that if I were to add those types, I could throw an error if the type of `Entity` was not define correctly.

**TL;DR: How do I quickly validate in my code that a constructor was run using all of the necessary arguments?**

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over an array of required properties and then checking `hasOwnProperty` would work...

```
const requiredProps = ['type', 'x', 'y', 'r', 'color'];
// ...

// Test the argument:
if (requiredProps.some(prop => !e.hasOwnProperty(prop))) {
  throw new Error('Required prop not found');
}
```

Or perhaps have `baseProps` for the `Entity`, and additional props for other subclasses:

```
const baseRequiredProps = ['type', 'x', 'y', 'r'];

// ...
class Entity {
  constructor(e) {
    const requiredProps = [...baseRequiredProps, ...(this.constructor.additionalRequiredProps || [])]
    if (requiredProps.some(prop => !e.hasOwnProperty(prop))) {
      throw new Error('Required prop not found');
    }

// ...
class Circle extends Entity {
  static additionalRequiredProps = ['color'];
```

In larger applications, I'd recommend approaching worries like this by using TypeScript instead, to *force* the caller to provide arguments of the desired type, without requiring any additional runtime code. It does take some getting used to, but it makes maintaining code a whole lot easier.

```
class Entity {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  constructor(e: Entity) {
      this.x = e.x;
      this.y = e.y;
  }
}
// works:
const e = new Entity({ x: 5, y: 10 });

class Circle extends Entity {
    type = 'circle';
    r: number;
    color: string;
    constructor(e: Circle) {
        super(e);
        this.type = e.type;
        this.r = e.r;
        this.color = e.color;
    }
}
// fails:
const c = new Circle({
    x: 5,
    y: 7,
    radius: 12,
    color: 'black',
    type: 'circle'
});
```

Since `radius` was accidentally typed instead of `r`, you get an error:

[image]